# Remote port forwarding or agent forwarding

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

It's about transfer files between two remote servers by my own laptop.

**Mac**: (MacOS) My own laptop already established ssh private-public key-auth with 3rd party **Cloud** server which I can ssh into it from **Mac**. **Mac** also can ssh into **Desktop** with a specific admin username.

**Cloud**: (Unix) A 3rd party storage provider.

**Desktop**: (Linux) A company server to store local data, can be ssh-ed by **Mac** only, not auth-ed to talk to **Cloud** directly.

*Question*: I need to download big data (TB) from **Cloud** to **Desktop**, while my **Mac** can not hold. How to do it?

Background:

- Know $rsync and $scp
- Know $ssh -L
- Limited knowledge about $ssh -A or $ssh -R and don't know how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **Mac**, run

```
scp -3 Cloud:big_data Desktop:.
```

That will transfer data from  **Cloud** to  **Desktop** through **Mac** without copying the data on **Mac**. You'll need a recent version of `scp`.

Comment: This works with small files. Is there an rsync version of this for big file?

Comment: `rsync` typically uses `ssh` behind the scenes anyway. There's nothing to gain by using `rsync` instead of `scp` unless you expect that the transfer might get interrupted and need to be resumed...